# Span not working in bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Span is not working in bootstrap v3.0.3.

```
 <div class="span4">    
        <div class="list-group">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link 3</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link 4</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`span` has become redundant in Bootstrap 3. It has now been replaced by `col-xx-#`, where `xx` can be `lg`, `md`, `sm` or `xs` and `#` ranges from 1 to 12. Read it up [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

Here's how your code should look like:

```
<div class="col-md-4">    
    <div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Link</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link 4</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Instead of `md`, you can use any of the above `xx` based on requirement.

Comment: Have there any alternative class?

Comment: `col-xx-#` IS the alternate class.

Comment: I would recommend you to read up the complete Bootstrap 3 documentation before proceeding. I too transitioned from 2.3.2 to 3 and there have been several changes in the classes.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.I have worked with  2.3.2.Now for a project I have to work by 3.0.3.I am going to read full documentation.

Answer (score 2):

As Ranveer mentioned, Bootstrap 3 no longer uses span and instead you would use .col-xx-4 (with xx being the minimum viewport size for the sizing to take effect [xs, sm, md, lg]). Here is the link for the documentation for more information: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid